# MySQL foreign keys' referenced table name always forced to lowercase

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, case-sensitive

First, create these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TAB_COMPANY (
  ID INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID),
  UNIQUE KEY(NAME)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TAB_DEPARTMENT (
  ID INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  COMPANYID INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID),
  INDEX FK_TAB_DEPARTMENT_TAB_COMPANY_COMPANYID(COMPANYID ASC),
  CONSTRAINT FK_TAB_DEPARTMENT_TAB_COMPANY_COMPANYID
    FOREIGN KEY (COMPANYID) REFERENCES TAB_COMPANY(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

Then show create table TAB_DEPARTMENT:

```
CREATE TABLE `TAB_DEPARTMENT` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `COMPANYID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_TAB_DEPARTMENT_TAB_COMPANY_COMPANYID` (`COMPANYID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_TAB_DEPARTMENT_TAB_COMPANY_COMPANYID` FOREIGN KEY (`COMPANYID`)
REFERENCES `tab_company` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The table name in foreign key reference clause is forced to lower case.

```
mysql> show variables like '%lower%';
lower_case_file_system ON
lower_case_table_names 0

mysql> show variables like 'version';
version 5.1.43-community
```

My platform is Window XP with SP3. I tested this on Linux, it is OK.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? I already reported a bug to MySQL.

I just tried on version 5.1.49-community, and the issue is still there.

Comment: Look for what the issue is, seeing nothing.  Table and column references are case insensitive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the reply from MySQL:

> From Miguel Solorzano:
>
> Thank you for the bug report. This a documented restriction of InnoDB
>   table:
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-restrictions.html
>
> "On Windows, InnoDB always stores database and table names internally
>   in lowercase. To move databases in a binary format from Unix to Windows
>   or from Windows to Unix, you should create all databases and tables
>   using lowercase names. "